# Can org-clock-display be made show estimates also?

Tags: org-mode

Currently, when you work with entries and clock things in/out, you can press:
`C-c C-x C-d` to display totals of entries next to them.

This uses the function org-clock-display: [source code here](https://github.com/yyr/org-mode/blob/master/lisp/org-clock.el#L1809)

It would be nice to be able to see estimates as well, like:

```
* my task  ... 2:00 / 3:00
```

Does anyone have any ideas on whether it's possible to add something like an advice function or another function that does this already?